# How to make org chart from external data source

Tags: jquery, json

I have an org chart from jquery org chart which is coming from plugin and internal json data,Everything is working fine but I am not getting here how to populate it with ajax call with the same data.Can anyone please help me.I am new to org chart.Thanks in advance.Here is my code below.

### html

```
<div id="chart-container"></div>

<a id="github-link" href="https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-square"></i></a>
```

### javascript

```
'use strict';

(function($){

  $(function() {

    var datascource = {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
            { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' }
      ]
    };

    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'data' : datascource,
      'nodeContent': 'title'
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

### css

```
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(http://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/img/background.jpg);
}

#github-link {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}

.orgchart {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.orgchart .node .title {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.orgchart .node .content {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #333;
}

.orgchart .node:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

.orgchart .node.focused {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

.orgchart .node .edge {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.orgchart .edge:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.orgchart td.left,
.orgchart td.top,
.orgchart td.right {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.orgchart td>.down {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create same json structure at server side. you can use following code then to build org chart.
lets say you are using asp.net mvc in backend then you need to use JsonResult action result to return json responce.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Organization Chart Plugin</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.orgchart.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      $.mockjax({
        url: '/orgchart/initdata',
        responseTime: 1000,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        responseText: {
          'name': 'Lao Lao',
          'title': 'general manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
                { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
                  'children': [
                    { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                    { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Li', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Wei', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Tie', 'title': 'department manager' }
          ]
        }
      });

      $('#chart-container').orgchart({
        'data' : '/orgchart/initdata',
        'nodeContent': 'title'
      });

    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please follow this https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

Comment: In this URL they have not given the coding example,only they have given example.As of now I just want to call from the json for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolve this,it may be useful for some one

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Organization Chart -- json datasource</title>  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/css/jquery.orgchart.css'>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/js/jquery.orgchart.js'></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### index.js

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'data' : '1.json',
      'depth': 2,
      'nodeContent': 'title'
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

### 1.json

```
{
    "name": "Lao Lao",
    "children": [{
            "name": "Bo Miao"
        },
        {
            "name": "Su Miao",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Tie Hua"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hei Hei",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Pang Pang"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Xiang Xiang"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Hong Miao"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chun Miao"
        }
    ]
}
```